# Proof on the Existence of Biholomorphic Maps

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and connected and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic and non-constant. Assume $f(z_0) = 0 $ for some $z_0 \in \Omega$ with order $k$. How can I show the existence of open sets $U_1, U_2, V_1, V_2$ and biholomorphic functions (i.e., holomorphic, bijective with holomorphic inverses) $\phi: U_1 \to U_2$ and $\psi: V_1 \to V_2$ such that $z_0 \in U_1, 0 \in U_2, V_1, V_2$ such that
\begin{align*}
\psi(f(\phi^{-1}(z))) = z^k
\end{align*}
for $z \in U_2$?

I am thinking of using Theorem 1.1 in Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis to first conclude that based on the assumptions on $f$, there exists an open set $U \in \Omega$ and a  non-vanishing holomorphic function $g$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(z) = (z-z_0)^kg(z)
\end{align*}
Then, the idea is that I let $U_1 = U$ and use $g$ to construct another map that contains $0$ in its image. This map would be $\phi$ so that $\phi$ is defined on $U_1$ and its image is $U_2$.

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, and I don't see how to deal with $\psi$ and $V_1,V_2$ and the composition I have to show. I would appreciate any help with this! Thanks!